# Admin can't install plugins

Tags: plugins

As the administrator of the website, I can't install or delete plugins.

- It's not a multisite install
- I have replaced *wp-admin* and *wp-includes* folders with fresh ones.
- It can't be because of the folder permissions (I copied the website on localhost-Windows and the problem is the same)
- I have deactivated all the plugins by renaming the *plugins* folder
- I have activated the default theme
- In the database, the user level is 10
- in the database, the capabilities is *a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}* https://prnt.sc/STgHnqwXJgjz

Note: the database tables don't have a prefix

Does anyone know what else could I do?
Thank you!

Comment: What is the error message you are getting while activating/deactivating plugins? Could be server permission issue. Does this happen when you try to install themes?

Comment: You're just not getting the add or delete options on the UI?

Comment: @Abhik, I got "Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page." when I tried to manually access *plugin-install.php*

Comment: @Rup, yes I didn't have the options in the UI

Comment: I found the problem [one of my colleagues did :) ]. In the config.php I had *define( 'DISALLOW_FILE_MODS', true );*

Comment: have you disabled all active plugins and tried again? Just because the database says you can do it does not mean that PHP code can't then change that when the code runs. Likewise, Administrator is _not_ a capability, it's a role, and roles have capabilities, that's what makes an adminstrator able to do more things than an editor. Role editing plugins or removal of capabilities from a role can do this

Comment: @Neluțu can you post that as an answer rather than a comment?

Comment: @TomJNowell, I did. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem. One of my colleagues did, thank you Simi :).
In the config.php I had

```php
define( 'DISALLOW_FILE_MODS', true );
```